# How to import a module with a manifest

Tags: powershell, import, module, manifest

Powershell is really testing my patience today... Ok, so I made a manifest to get my required assemblies. Now how do I properly import when I have a *.psm1 and *.psd1 file.

folder path: C:\mypath\blah\blah\Module\Format-XML\

files in folder: Format-XML.psd1, Format-XML.psm1

```
Import-Module -Name "C:\mypath\blah\blah\Module\Format-XML\Format-XML"
```

Then when I got to use my function in my module called from another script, for whatever reason, doesn't exist/work. What am I doing wrong?

[ERROR] VERB-NOUN: The term 'VERB-NOUN' is not recognized as the name of a

[ERROR] cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the

[ERROR] name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

In the *.psd1:

```
FunctionsToExport = '*'
```

In the *.psm1:

```
#I know... not required but I tried anyways... :(
Export-ModuleMember -Function '*'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: Don't forget to set your root module in the manifest... *sigh*

Answer (score 4):

So exactly following code need to be added to your psd1.

```
# Script module or binary module file associated with this manifest.
RootModule = 'nameOfYourModule.psm1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the module that's imported. You can do this this 2 ways:

After import:

```
$mod = Get-Module -Name Format-XML
```

During import:

```
$mod = Import-Module -Name "C:\mypath\blah\blah\Module\Format-XML\Format-XML" -PassThru
```

Then you can check `$mod` and look at the `.ExportedCommands` property. Is anything listed?

Also try removing the second `Format-XML` (I'm assuming that last component refers to the module itself and not the folder).

Comment: I have a folder named Format-XML though, should I put it in the Module folder?

Comment: @user3812871 could you run `tree C:\mypath\blah\blah\Module\Format-XML` and edit the result into your question?

Comment: @user3812871 also check exported commands and see if the function you expected to be there shows up or not.

Comment: No subfolders exist on tree, and exported commands shows nothing.

Comment: @user3812871 can you edit the module code and manifest into your question? The function definition is more important than the body of it if you want to leave it out..